# Was the original Yiddish lost in the Hebrew sichos?

Tags: chabad, yiddish

The sichos (speeches) of the Lubavicher Rebbe were alternately published: some in the original Yiddish and some translated into Hebrew.  Therefore some sichos are published only in translated form (since all the sichos were delivered by the Rebbe in Yiddish).

Does this mean the original Yiddish version of those sichos have been lost?  What was the intent in publishing them only translated into Hebrew?

Comment: You're mistaken. The Sichos of the Lubavitcher Rebbe were published in the original Yiddish first, before being translated into Hebrew.

Comment: But Likutei Sichos alternates between Yiddish and Hebrew... Where do I find the Yiddish versions of the Hebrew ones?

Comment: You would have to find someone with the original hanachos. I had many volumes of Sefer HaSichos (in Yiddish) years ago, but have given them to people who couldn't afford seforim and spoke Yiddish.

Comment: You ask two questions in your post, "Does this mean the original Yiddish version of those sichos have been lost? What was the intent in publishing them only translated into Hebrew?" and completely different one in a comment, "Where do I find the Yiddish versions of the Hebrew ones?". If you mean to ask the latter, then [edit] your question to say so before it attracts answers you're not looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The original lekute sichos were published in Hebrew and Yiddish with most being published in Yiddish. The entire set which is made up of 39 volumes were heavily edited by the Lubavitcher Rebbe both in regards to the specific words as well as adding in many of the sources in the footnotes. Since the set was published there have been many translations of many of these books including a translation of sichos originally published in Yiddish into Hebrew. As if yet there is not a full set translated into any language but many do appear in stores in Hebrew, English, Russian, Spanish, and other languages.